# The condition number of block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, block-matrices, condition-number

> Let $$A = \begin{pmatrix} I & B\\ B^H & I\end{pmatrix}$$ with $\|B\|_2 < 1$. Show that $$\|A\|_2 \cdot \|A^{-1}\|_2 = \frac{1 + \|B\|_2}{1 - \|B\|_2}$$

My attempt:

I know that $$||A||_2||A^{-1}||_2=\frac{\sigma_\max}{\sigma_\min}$$ where $\sigma_\max$ and $\sigma_\min$  are the largest and smallest singular values. But I don´t know how to use the fact that $||B||_2<1.$

Someone could help me?

Comment: Not an answer, but $||B||<1$ implies that both $I-B$ and $I+B$ are invertible and $||(I-B)^{-1}||\leq 1/(1-||B||)$ and $||(I+B)^{-1}||\leq 1/(1+||B||)$. Not only this, but the 2-norm has the property that $||B^H||_2=||B||_2$ (assuming that the superscript $H$ means conjugate transpose)

Comment: Notice that we can write $A = I + C$, where $C = \begin{pmatrix}0 & B \\ B^H & 0\end{pmatrix}$. If you can show that $||C||_2 = ||B||_2$, then you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b_1\ge\ldots\ge b_n\ge0$ be the singular values of $B$, where $n$ is the smaller dimension of $B$. Then $A$ is unitarily similar to $\pmatrix{1&b_1\\ b_1&1}\oplus\cdots\oplus\pmatrix{1&b_n\\ b_n&1}\oplus I$. The condition that $\|B\|_2<1$ ensures that the smallest eigenvalue of $A$, namely $1-b_1$, is positive. The result now follows easily.